# Is there another way to "push-to-deploy" with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket, google-cloud-platform

This two-year-old BitBucket “push-to-deploy” (https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html) option looks really useful/interesting but seems like it’s no longer functional. The link in step 8 seems to have disappeared.

Is it possible to use this general feature somehow even if it doesn’t seem to work with BitBucket anymore?

If anyone has any ideas, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins for continuous integration and continuous deployment. You could take a look on https://jenkins.io/ .

Comment: Another suggestion is circleCI, they even have free tier for closed projects.